# Remapping A Virtual On-Screen Keyboard (OSK)?

Tags: microsoft-surface, remapping, on-screen-keyboard

I used TweakKey to remap a key on my Surface Book 2. I found that the change worked on the physical keyboard, but not on the OSK. Is there a way to re-map the OSK?

I know how to do so with AutoHotKey, but I was hoping for a more organic method. I tried out Hot Virtual Keyboard, but it seems to be quite limited regarding the keys it'll remap. Also, I'm ticked off by that program because it refuses to exit.

Comment: Just a heads up about AHK. You can map the ESC button to exit your script by calling the ExitApp function. Or you can click on 'show hidden icons' on the bottom right of your start bar and right click 'exit' the green 'H' app thats running there to exit as well.

Comment: @Myles Not AHK, it's Hot Virtual Keyboard that won't exit.